# how to draw a full circle gluon loop using Tikz-feynman?

Tags: luatex, tikz-feynman

[image]

how to draw a full circle gluon loop using tikz-feynman?

I can't find the way to draw a full circle in manual, but half circle. So using half circle I draw the diagram, but it can't be satisfying.

```
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to c] {
            a -- [gluon, momentum=\(k\),edge label'={\(a,\mu\)}]  b -- [gluon, momentum=\(k\),edge label'={\(b,\nu\)}] c,
            b -- [gluon, half left] d -- [gluon, half left] b
        };
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far?

Comment: It's described in the manual, just search for "ctan tikz-feynman". And it may be worth to have a look into the category, as well: https://ctan.org/topic/physics . Also, have a look to the right, at "Related" links.

Comment: Please complete your code, i.e. "decorate" it, starting wint \documentclass, ending with \end{document}. This way we can copy & compile your code right away.

Comment: Right, that seems to be what package tikz-feynman offers. If you find it not satisfying enough, a few options: a) contact the packages author, b) create a tikz-drawing yourself and combine it with tikz-feynman, c) try one of the other feynman-packages at ctan.org .